# Hide / Show list with angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a DL list that is rendered at server side:

```
<dl>
  <dt>dt 01</dt>
  <dd>dd 01</dd>
  <dt>dt 02</dt>
  <dd>dd 02</dd>
</dl>
```

I would like to hide / show a DD when a DT is clicked. But I also need to change both the dt and the dd class when this happens.

Can I do this with angular? Do I need, or should I use, a controller for this?

Comment: Do you have control over the server side rendering?

Comment: Would be a very simple angular directive.

Comment: Yes i have. I can render whatever I want. But the html is rendered server side.

Comment: How is it inserted? Approach would be different if using `ng-bind-html` or if it is part of an angular template

Comment: @charlietfl: could you, Please,  give me a simple example of such a directive?

Comment: The code is rendered in the html page so i do not want do use angular template.

Comment: rendered on page load you mean as part of main page?

Comment: As @charlietfl commented a good approach would be to wrap it in a directive. However, if you want to do things the "angular" way, it would be better to not have the server render HTML at all, but rather return the data in JSON format and use the HTML as the template.

Comment: I understand but in this case the html contains some images and so on and it is static html content. I just want to use angular to add the show and hide feature and change class.

Comment: @Miguel angular includes `angular.element` which is a subset of jQuery methods. So code in directive would basically be jQuery . Not hard to find out how to make a simple directive or how to toggle elements in a click handler

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/o4ohel/pen/gaLbMq)  to get you started. It's not a complete solution but should point you in right direction.

and here's the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <dl toggle-desc>
    <dt>dt 01</dt>
    <dd>dd 01</dd>
    <dt>dt 02</dt>
    <dd>dd 02</dd>
  </dl>
</body>
```

And JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
}).directive('toggleDesc', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var dtList = element.find('dt');
      dtList.bind('click', function(evt) {
        //TODO: Hide/show next sibling, change class names etc.
      });
    }
  };
});
```